# How to change background color of an OpenGL surface?

Tags: python, opengl, graphics, background, pygame

Having

```
srf = pygame.display.set_mode(viewport, OPENGL | DOUBLEBUF)
```

and performing

```
srf.fill([255,255,255])
```

results in the following error message:

```
pygame.error: Cannot call on OPENGL Surfaces
```

How to solve this issue? How can I change the background color?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the [`glClearColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml) function to set the color you want to clear your screen to, and then use [`glClear`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) to actually clear the screen with the color specified.

E.g. call

```
glClearColor(0.7, 0, 0, 1)
```

to set the color to red and then call

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
```

to clear the screen to this color.